# Crystal Reports 10 Command Object Change Datasource Location

Tags: crystal-reports

I have used command objects in my Crystal Report and now I need to change the Data Source.
  I have followed the instructions found in KnowledgeBase Article c2016958 and downloaded, unzipped and applied cr10win_en.zip and dbex10win_en.zip but I still never get my connection updated.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Were you able to solve it? 
I am running 64 bit Windows 7 and CR 10.

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: What happens when you try to update the data source per the instructions in the article?

Comment: I select the Command in the upper pane, the add command in the lower pane, press the UPDATE button and the box where you add the SQL to the command appears.  I add my SQL on the left side, create my parameters on the right side, press the OK button and wait forever.  Nothing is ever changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I imagine it is the same process for CR10 as it is for CRXI and onwards:

1. Go to 'Set Datasource Location'
2. In the top pane, highlight the **datasource** and not the command. The datasource has a yellow cylinder with a plug icon.
3. In the bottom pane, highlight the **new datasource** you want the command to point at. Do not highlight 'Add Command' as that will create a new command on the new datasource. The command must contain valid SQL for the new datasource. Note that you shouldn't have to add any new code or parameters.
4. Hit update. Crystal will probably ask you to provide values to the parameters before it completes the update.

If SQL is valid, you should have an updated datasource for your report.

Comment: It was the 'Add Command' highlight that I think was the problem!  Thanks for this and I think it would have worked if the designers didn't have DIFFERENT table names in LIVE and TEST!!!