# How to edit an existing query in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i just can see the SQL query at "Database"->"Show SQL Query". How do I edit it in Crystal Report?

Comment: How query is getting generated... i mean by table linking or you are writing a query in that place?

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for `Edit Command` within the Database Expert ... see the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Hi AHiggins, I have tried the above but am not getting the edit option. any suggestion to enable this option ?

Comment: I found [this walkthrough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401764/crystal-reports-10-command-object-change-datasource-location) which might help you with the step-by-step ...

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Database Fields >> Database Expert
2. Select all the tables required for the report (Selected Tables section)
3. Go to the tab: Links
4. Drag and create all the links required to connect the tables links.
5. **Then you can right click on the link and select Link Options**
   **Here you can change your joins and your final SQL query will change accordingly.**

Answer (score 1):

For Crystal Reports 14.1.x, use Report (in menu at the top) ==> Selection Formulas ==> Record

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you need to provide what version of CR you are using.

Secondly, to the best of my knowledge in Version CR13 using VS2010, you **CANNOT** hand edit SQL query like it we could in older version of CR.

Only way to change it is to update the links/joins on the tables in the Database Expert and Verify Database. These joins will then reflect when you click "Show SQL query".

Thirdly, there is a way you can control the query yourself, using "SQL Command". The steps to do this is mentioned in the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

First Right Click on Database Fields > Set Datasource Location > Select View which you want to replace with another.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently upgraded to VS 2019 with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 13 SP25.  The right click "Edit Command" option wasn't there for me either but I know it was in the past.  However I finally did get it by using a toolbar that was added and a "Select Expert Record" option.  The same option should be under the "Report" menu in the full version of Crystal Reports.

Comment: Hi @Allan, could you please share the link from where you downloaded SP25? Thanks

Comment: Sure:  https://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/  The site is pretty badly designed.  Like the right side has a form to fill out to get access (it's free) but the form doesn't show up in FireFox.  Chrome works though.

Comment: I don't see the form on both Firefox and Chrome using that link. However, I have found an alternative official link which along with the latest version, has many previous versions too. Just sort by published date and voile! Here's the link:

https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html