# Crystal Reports, Link Subreport To Date Group

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report to show our overall quality tending over time by month or quarter (over a span of several years).  The main report will show all of our shipments over the specified time period grouped by month/quarter, and the sub report will show all returns entered during that month/quarter that result in scrap or rework.

The issue I am having is linking the sub report to the date group in the main report.  After several attempts using different methods, the best I could do is show all returns within the date parameter in every group footer.

This is my first time posting, so I'm not sure what additional info will be needed to assist.  Please let me know if there is more needed.

*Edit for additional info

I would like the subreport to show data for each month or quarter in the given time period.  So if the date range of the report is for 1/1/2018 - 9/30/2018 and the data is grouped by month, I would like the subreport to show only the data from each month group.  General layout below.

**January**
Shipments
Returns (subreport showing data for January)

**February**
Shipments
Returns (subreport showing data for February)

*Second edit to add screenshot and more info

I stripped all the parameters from the subreport because I couldn't get any of them to work.  The only parameter on the main report is the Date Range that prompts users for a start and end date.

The main report has the shipments in the details section.

Current layout below.  If I can get this current issue resolved, I will be adding values passed up from the subreport to calculate the quality rating for each month, then passing them back down to a second subreport to summarize and chart.

[Quality Trend Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdWsZ.png)

*Third edit for data source and example data

The main and subreports are pulled from tables in our company database.

SQL query used for the main report.  Only the "Releases" table is used to show how many and when each part was shipped.  `DelType=0` is specifying a customer delivery.  The date range is defined by a user entered parameter.

**Main Report**

```
SELECT 
"Releases"."DateComplete",  
"Releases"."DelType",  
"Releases"."PartNo",  
"Releases"."Qty",  
"Releases"."JobNo",  
"Releases"."PartDesc"  

FROM   "COMPANY"."dbo"."Releases" "Releases"  

WHERE  "Releases"."DelType"=0 AND  
("Releases"."DateComplete">={ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'} AND  
"Releases"."DateComplete"<{ts '2018-10-01 00:00:00'})
```

I am trying to use `CustReturn.DateEnt` as the datetime link to `Releases.DateComplete` in the main report (not currently linked at a paramter because it didn't work), and only select records that are customer returns resulting in rework, scrap, sort, or repair.

**Subreport**

```
SELECT 
"CustReturn"."DateEnt",  
"CustReturn"."CustRMANo",  
"CustReturnDet"."OrigJobNo",  
"CustReturnDet"."PartNo",  
"CustReturnDet"."QtyReturned",  
"CustReturnDet"."QtyToRework",  
"CustReturnDet"."QtyToRestock",  
"NonConformance"."Disposition",  
"NonConformance"."ReturnType",  
"CustReturn"."IssueDate",  
"NonConformance"."NonConfDate",  
"CustReturnDet"."PartDesc"  

FROM   
("COMPANY"."dbo"."CustReturn" "CustReturn" INNER JOIN "COMPANY"."dbo"."CustReturnDet" "CustReturnDet" ON "CustReturn"."CustRMANo"="CustReturnDet"."CustRMANo")    
LEFT OUTER JOIN "COMPANY"."dbo"."NonConformance" "NonConformance" ON "CustReturnDet"."NonConfNo"="NonConformance"."NonConfNo"

WHERE  ("NonConformance"."Disposition"='REPAIR' OR  
"NonConformance"."Disposition"='REWORK' OR  
"NonConformance"."Disposition"='SCRAP' OR  
"NonConformance"."Disposition"='SORT') AND  
"NonConformance"."ReturnType"='CUSTOMER'
```

[Quality Trend Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgNvX.png)

Comment: To clarify, you need the subreport to show only data for a given month? Or for a given quarter?

Comment: @4444 Added additional info to my question.

Comment: What are the parameters of your subreport? Are you using a Details section in the main report?
Can you post a screenshot of your current design layout (without the subreport is fine)?

Comment: @digital.aaron Added additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to give a big thanks to Digital.Aaron.  Your help in solving this is greatly appreciated.

Your answer was quite close to what I needed.  I was still unable to get the subreport to show any data after adding the additional lines to the SQL statement, so I tried something a little different.  I made the additional statements into formula fields.

**Main Report Field**

`DATEADD("D", -1*(DATEPART("D",{Releases.DateComplete})-1),{Releases.DateComplete})`

**Subreport Field**

`DATEADD("D", -1*(DATEPART("D",{CustReturn.DateEnt})-1),{CustReturn.DateEnt})`

I used these fields as the link between the main report and subreport, but still couldn't get the data to show.  The issue turned out to be setting them as `=` to each other in the record select formula of the subreport.  I named the formulas `DatePeriod`

**Original Record Select**

`{@DatePeriod} = {?Pm-@DatePeriod}`

**Modified Record Select**

`{@DatePeriod} in Date({?Pm-@DatePeriod})`

Once I made the change, everything fell into place.

Thanks again,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're grouping on `Releases.DateComplete`. Let's assume this value is the same for all records associated with a given month. Let's also assume the following (simplified) sample data for `Shipments`:

```
ShipmentDate | PartNo | Qty | DateComplete
01/01/2018   | 0001   | 1   | 01/31/2018
01/05/2018   | 0031   | 10  | 01/31/2018
01/31/2018   | A314   | 4   | 01/31/2018
```

Your `Returns` data would then need to look something like this:

```
ReturnDate   | PartNo | Qty | DateComplete
01/15/2018   | 0031   | 7   | 01/31/2018
```

Notice they both have a `DateComplete` column.

Now in your Crystal Report template, you'll use the DateComplete field from the main report results set as the input to your subreport parameter. Your design layout looks like it would be correct here, as you'll want the subreport to be called in the group footer.

EDIT: So it looks like DateComplete is not the same for all records in a given month. That's fine. We're going to add a column to both the main query and the subreport query that WILL be the same for all records in a given month, and that we can then use to link the records.

Your main query would become:

```
SELECT 
    Releases.DateComplete,  
    Releases.DelType,  
    Releases.PartNo,  
    Releases.Qty,  
    Releases.JobNo,  
    Releases.PartDesc,
    DatePeriod = DATEADD(DAY, -1*(DATEPART(DAY,Releases.DateComplete)-1),Releases.DateComplete) 
FROM   COMPANY.dbo.Releases Releases  
WHERE  Releases.DelType=0 
    AND (Releases.DateComplete>={ts '2018-01-01 00:00:00'} AND  Releases.DateComplete<{ts '2018-10-01 00:00:00'})
```

Your subreport query would then become:

```
SELECT 
    CustReturn.DateEnt,  
    CustReturn.CustRMANo,  
    CustReturnDet.OrigJobNo,  
    CustReturnDet.PartNo,  
    CustReturnDet.QtyReturned,  
    CustReturnDet.QtyToRework,  
    CustReturnDet.QtyToRestock,  
    NonConformance.Disposition,  
    NonConformance.ReturnType,  
    CustReturn.IssueDate,  
    NonConformance.NonConfDate,  
    CustReturnDet.PartDesc,
    DatePeriod = DATEADD(DAY, -1*(DATEPART(DAY,CustReturn.DateEnt)-1),CustReturn.DateEnt)  
FROM COMPANY.dbo.CustReturn CustReturn 
INNER JOIN COMPANY.dbo.CustReturnDet CustReturnDet ON CustReturn.CustRMANo = CustReturnDet.CustRMANo    
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY.dbo.NonConformance NonConformance ON CustReturnDet.NonConfNo = NonConformance.NonConfNo
WHERE  NonConformance.ReturnType='CUSTOMER'
AND (   
        NonConformance.Disposition='REPAIR' 
        OR NonConformance.Disposition='REWORK' 
        OR NonConformance.Disposition='SCRAP' 
        OR NonConformance.Disposition='SORT'
    )
```

`DatePeriod` will always be the date of the first day of the month. Now we can use this as the Link field between the main report and the subreport. You could also consider making this the field that you Group on, instead of the month value.

Comment: Hi @digital.aaron.  I may not be understanding you correctly, but this method did not work for me.  The subreport is only picking out one date of each month to show returns as opposed to all returns during the month.

Comment: This technique really depends on being able to pass the subreport a single date to have it return all the records from the month. What are the sources of data for the main report and for the subreport? Are they SQL stored procs? A data table somewhere? Can you show some examples of the data, and how you're retrieving it to pass to your Crystal Report?

Comment: added additional info in the main question.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies.  Would I add this additional text to the SQL query through a "SQL Expression Field" or "Set Datasource Location"?

Comment: I should probably have mentioned earlier that I am using Crystal Reports 11.

Comment: Where are you currently getting the SQL queries for the main report and subreport from? Are they embedded in the configuration of your datasource (i.e. datasource is a query), or do they live in a stored proc(s) that gets called by the report?

Comment: Through Database → Show SQL Query.  The tables are added by connecting the database through Database Expert, then adding each table and creating the links.

Comment: Take a look at this post and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26235374/1169697

Comment: Answer posted.  Thanks for your help.